# Access Controller method from another Class MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, controller

I have a HomeController with a method foo ().
Now I would like to access the method foo () of the HomeController from a normal class Class.cs.
How do I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.Net Core, you can add your custom class and the Controllers in your `Startup.cs` file:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<MyClass>();
        services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Afterwards you can inject the controller in a custom class:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(MyController controller)
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Then you can request an instance of the custom class (e.g. `serviceProvider.GetService<MyClass>()`) and the controller will be injected into this class.

Comment: where is the going serviceProvider.GetService<MyClass>() ? In MyClass? and is this  public MyClass(MyController controller)
    {
       // ...
    } a constructor?

Comment: E.g. from the host in the Program class in the main-method (`var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build(); var cl = host.Services.GetService<MyClass>();`). The best would be if the class in which MyClass is needed is also created using dependency injection, then the class could be injected into the constructor.

Comment: public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
           
        }
 
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
       
    }
this is my program class, where should i add serviceProvider.GetService<MyClass>()?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return view from another controller you will have to use one of Redirect methods.

If you need to reuse some code, the easiest way would be to create another class , Common for example and put metod foo there, better as a static.

```
public class Common
{
public static void Foo() {}
}
```

after this you can use it from any place in your code, from any action of any controller

```
public classs HomeController:Controller
{
   public IActionResult MyAction()
   {
           Common.Foo();
          .....other code
         return View();
    }
}
```

PS. I don't think that it is good idea to create and inject the whole controller or the class for using only one of its methods.

Ps2. If Foo code contains some code to work with dbContext, it is a better idea to create a repository and put the code there.

Answer (score 0):

Usually,we will put the method into a service,and register it in startup.cs.And then use DI to get the service.Then call methods in the service.If you want to call a method in a controller.You can also do like this directly:

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        

        public HomeController()
        {
        }
        public string foo()
        {
            return "Calling foo!";
        }
    }
```

MyClass:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public string callFoo()
        {
            HomeController h = new HomeController();
            return h.foo();
        }
    }
```

TestAction:

```
public void Index()
{
    MyClass n = new MyClass();
    var s = n.callFoo();
}
```